# No default handler could be found for ActionBean - Stripes 1.5

Tags: java, stripes

I'm trying to follow the tutorial Calculator on the stripes site.
https://stripesframework.atlassian.net/wiki/display/STRIPES/Quick+Start+Guide

but always appear the following message:
HTTP Status 500 - No default handler could be found for ActionBean of type: calculate.CalculatorActionBean

My ActionBean:

```
   @UrlBinding("/calculate/Calculator.action")
public class CalculatorActionBean implements ActionBean {
    private ActionBeanContext context;
    private double numberOne;
    private double numberTwo;
    private double result;

    public ActionBeanContext getContext() { return context; }
    public void setContext(ActionBeanContext context) { this.context = context; }

    public double getNumberOne() { return numberOne; }
    public void setNumberOne(double numberOne) { this.numberOne = numberOne; }

    public double getNumberTwo() { return numberTwo; }
    public void setNumberTwo(double numberTwo) { this.numberTwo = numberTwo; }

    public double getResult() { return result; }
    public void setResult(double result) { this.result = result; }

    @DefaultHandler
    public Resolution addition() {
        result = getNumberOne() + getNumberTwo();
        return new ForwardResolution("/WEB-INF/jsp/layout-usage.jsp");
    }
}
```

My Jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8" 
    isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="stripes" uri="http://stripes.sourceforge.net/stripes.tld" %>

<%--<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" scope="page" />--%>

 <stripes:form beanclass="calculate.CalculatorActionBean" focus="">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Number 1:</td>
            <td><stripes:text name="numberOne"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Number 2:</td>
            <td><stripes:text name="numberTwo"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <stripes:submit name="addition" value="Add"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Result:</td>
            <td>${actionBean.result}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</stripes:form>
```

Comment: The code you provide runs fine when I drop it in a Stripes project so it probably is some config issue. What is in the `ActionResolver.Packages` init param of `StripesFilter` in your `web.xml`?

Comment: you save my day! the parameter was blank! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ActionResolver.Packages init parameter was blank! Thanks! @acdhirr

Comment: Cheers! Happy Striping!